# Extract digits and operators from math arithmetic expression using java 8 new features

Tags: java, java-8

I m trying to write arithmetic expression evaluation in java 8.Following is code written in java 6 but I want to implement it in Java 8 using lambda ,streams n collectors.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) 
{ 
    if (tokens[i] == ' ') 
        continue; 
    if (tokens[i] >= '0' && tokens[i] <= '9') 
    { 
      StringBuffer sbuf = new StringBuffer(); 

      while (i < tokens.length && tokens[i] >= '0' && tokens[i] <= '9') 
      sbuf.append(tokens[i++]); 
      values.push(Integer.parseInt(sbuf.toString())); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
Arrays.stream(tokens)
            .filter(Character::isDigit)
            .map(Character::getNumericValue)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(Stack<Integer>::new));
```

by your solution not to need `while` loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
   if (Character.isDigit(tokens[i]))             
     values.push(Character.getNumericValue(tokens[i]));
}
```